# What is the appropriate Exception to throw upon a runtime type mismatch in C#

Tags: c#, exception, mono.cecil

Essentially I am creating a little IL injection DLL that uses MONO.CECIL and C#, primarily as a learning exercise for myself but also for my own future hobbyist use.

I am not particularly skilled with exceptions (or C#) and am unsure what the appropriate exception to throw is for when a runtime type mismatch occurs.

For example : I have a method that INJECTS a method call at a given point in a target DLL. The method takes as an arguement a Collection (parameters) to represent the variables to pass as parameters to the newly injected method call.

Before injecting I check for type parity between each member of the Collection (parameters) and the Collection from the method whose call I am injecting.

On a mismatch I want to throw an exception. But I could not really find any that fit. I would prefer to use existing exceptions where possible, rather than creating my own.

Here is the code :

```
  private static bool ParameterParity(Collection<ParameterDefinition> p, Collection<VariableDefinition> v)
        {
            if (p.Count != v.Count)
            {
                return (false);
            }
            else
            {
                int index = 0;
                foreach (ParameterDefinition parameter in p)
                {
                    if (parameter.ParameterType.MetadataType != v[index].VariableType.MetadataType)
                    {
                        return (false);
                    }
                    index++;
                }
            }
            return (true);
        }
```

Here is the call where the exception will be thrown :

```
 if (ParameterParity(source.Parameters, parameters) == false)
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException($"{Helper.AddParenthesis(nameof(PreInject), Helper.ParenthesisE.Square)}" +
                         $" : Parameter mismatch in TYPE or NUMBER" +
                         $". Functionality not supported.");
                }
```

I temporarily have used the NOT IMPLEMENTED exception, but would prefer something more appropriate. A suggestion as to the appropriate Exception would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's probably ultimately an `ArgumentException`? A method somewhere was given some arguments, and something was wrong with one or more of them

Comment: Use an existing exception if it is not going to get caught and the user needs to figure it out by themselves.  If it is going to get caught however then you must make sure that you never accidentally catch one that's raised by other code.  Thus you create your own.